# How to generate id's in sequence - Play Framework 2.3.4

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I have this class:

```
@Entity
public class Sale extends Model {

    // ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long number;

    // ...

}
```

When I call save on the first sale, its number becomes 1, but when I call save on the second sale, its number becomes 33. How can I make the @Id numbers be generated in a sequence (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)?

Comment: Short generic answer: don't use an 'Id' for a sequence that *must* be compact/linear. (In many cases desiring IDs as such reveals a lack of an appropriately orderable column.)

Comment: Anyway, see http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/07/29/setting-up-sequential-ids-using-jpa-tablegenerator FWIW

Comment: If I use another attribute, I would have to query for the maximum attribute already on the table, and I guess this costs a lot. Can you suggest a better way to have that attribute generated sequentiallly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use it like this:

@Id
    private Long id;

and it generates in in sequence I tried it in both MYSql and SQLite.